# Difference of 2 columns of query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, difference

I have a `VoteQuestion` table: `VoteQuestion(idUser → User, idQuestion → Content, isUp)`

and a `Question` table: `Question(idQuestion → Content, title)`

I want to select the 5 questions with the best score (upvotes-downvotes).
An upvote is a `VoteQuestion` with `isUp = TRUE` and a downvote a `VoteQuestion` with `isUp = FALSE`.

I tried the following query, but it's not what I was looking for. It's giving the same score for every question.

```
WITH upvotes AS
( 
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS "a"
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS TRUE
), 
downvotes AS
( 
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS "b"
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS FALSE
)
SELECT "title", "Question"."idQuestion", upvotes."a"-downvotes."b" AS total
FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question", upvotes, downvotes
WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
GROUP BY "title", "Question"."idQuestion", upvotes."a", downvotes."b"
ORDER BY "total" DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Also tried this:

```
SELECT "title", "Question"."idQuestion", 
( SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS TRUE
) AS upvotes, 
( SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS FALSE
) AS downvotes, upvotes-downvotes AS total
FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
GROUP BY "title", "Question"."idQuestion"
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 5
```

but it says `ERROR:  column "upvotes" does not exist`

How can I get the difference of the upvotes and downvotes in a column from the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a conditional statement inline to convert your `True` and `False` values to numbers (1 and -1 respectively) you can simply sum up the votes like this:

```
SELECT
    q."title",
    q."idQuestion",
    sum(
       case
           when v."isUp" then 1
           else -1
       end
    ) AS total

FROM
    VoteQuestion v join Question q on v."idQuestion" = q."idQuestion"

GROUP BY
    q."title",
    q."idQuestion"

ORDER BY
    3 DESC

LIMIT 5
```

I haven't tried it yet but I'm pretty sure this works.

EDIT:
Here's the SQLFiddle which runs successfully: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/df4ca/3

Comment: Yes, tried this and it works. By the way, you have a typo - `ORDER BY total DESC`. Appreciate your answer, thanks!

Comment: `ORDER BY 3 DESC` refers to column total as it is the third column in the projection.

Comment: Double-quotes around table names are probably required for CaMeL-case names (`"VoteQuestion"`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT "title", "Question"."idQuestion", 
( SELECT COUNT(*) as upvotes
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS TRUE
) AS upvt, 
( SELECT COUNT(*) as downvotes
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS FALSE
) AS downvt, upvt.upvotes-downvt.downvotes AS total
FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
GROUP BY "title", "Question"."idQuestion"
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Hope it helps you

**UPDATE**

Let's try this one:

```
SELECT "title", "Question"."idQuestion", 
upvotes, downvotes, upvotes-downvotes AS total
FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question",
( SELECT "idQuestion", COUNT(*) as upvotes
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS TRUE GROUP BY "idQuestion"
) AS upvt, 
( SELECT "idQuestion", COUNT(*) as downvotes
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS FALSE GROUP BY "idQuestion"
) AS downvt
WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
AND "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = downvt."idQuestion"
AND "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = upvt."idQuestion"
GROUP BY "title", "Question"."idQuestion"
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried something similar to that before coming here. As it is, it says `missing FROM-clause entry for table upvt`. Then I add `upvt` in the `FROM`-clause and it says `relation "upvt" does not exist`. Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: Test every part separatly. First do this: SELECT COUNT(*) as upvotes
  FROM "VoteQuestion", "Question"
  WHERE "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"
  AND "VoteQuestion"."isUp" IS TRUE
Does it gives you the upvotes?

Comment: There's a condition missing there - `AND "VoteQuestion"."idQuestion" = "Question"."idQuestion"`. Apart from that, yes, it gives me the upvotes.

Comment: Having some error on the `GROUP BY` line, don't know why. However, the other answer makes this much more compact and easier to read.